# Postgresql out of memory during transaction

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, transactions

Trying to debug an out of memory error with Postgresql.

Simple:

- Open Connection

  - begin transaction
  - trying to import about 20GBytes of data (40K rows + rest large image blob's)
  - end transaction
- Close Connection

What I notice is that the python app stays around 200Mbytes of memory usage, but the postgres process on my MacOSX 10.9.5 is growing and growing. Until it runs out of memory (running 32-bit version).

Sqlalchemy, 0.9.5, psycopg2 2.6, python 2.7.5, postgresql 9.3.2 (default config settings)

I have the impression that postgresql is buffering the whole transaction until, I commit or rollback. I couldn't find anything that says there is flag in config for this to turn that on or off.

Question:

- any way to change postgresql behavior so it doesn't keep this whole transaction in memory?
- anything that can prevent postgresql to store a transaction to disk. I don't do any locks.

Error I see:

```
(45845,0xa0db51a8) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
TopMemoryContext: 64727172 total in 7901 blocks; 132784 free (7871 chunks); 64594388 used
  CFuncHash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 4936 free (0 chunks); 3256 used
  PL/Python procedures: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 4872 free (0 chunks); 3320 used
  SPI exceptions: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 2328 free (0 chunks); 5864 used
  Rendezvous variable hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 3848 free (0 chunks); 4344 used
  TopTransactionContext: 3859664 total in 6 blocks; 98504 free (31 chunks); 3761160 used
    CurTransactionContext: 0 total in 0 blocks; 0 free (0 chunks); 0 used

.... (thousands of these)

    pg_authid_rolname_index: 1024 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 472 used
  MdSmgr: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 5320 free (0 chunks); 2872 used
  ident parser context: 0 total in 0 blocks; 0 free (0 chunks); 0 used
  hba parser context: 7168 total in 3 blocks; 2680 free (3 chunks); 4488 used
  LOCALLOCK hash: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 13080 free (3 chunks); 11496 used
  Timezones: 78520 total in 2 blocks; 5968 free (0 chunks); 72552 used
  ErrorContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 8176 free (3 chunks); 16 used
ERROR:  spiexceptions.OutOfMemory: out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 2016.
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
    PL/Python function "metavalue_cleanup", line 25, in <module>
      TD["new"]["id"]))
  PL/Python function "metavalue_cleanup"
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO metavalue (id_item, id_metatype, id_employee, date, value) VALUES (5079, 1, 1, now(), 'J107') RETURNING metavalue.id
```

Comment: `PL/Python function "metavalue_cleanup"` : This looks like you have PL/Pyhon installed ...

Comment: Indeed PL/Python is used for several database triggers, during the import, several of these get triggered.

Comment: Personally, I would get rid of them ASAP. Garbage collect and DBMSses don't mix well. BTW: the number 8K in `SPI exceptions: 8192` looks suspect. A

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just dropped all the database triggers to see if the issue was there, and indeed no memory blow up in that case, will dig further now thanks for the help.

Comment: @wildplasser Python is reference-counted not garbage-collected, but the point's taken. This suggests a possible reference count leak in PL/Python, though it's hard to say without a proper example with the trigger code, trigger create statements, table definitions, etc.

Comment: Does not *need* to be a reference leak BTW. Could be that references are kept until commit time. (eg: because they all share a common great-parent: the session, or transaction)